# Dar toggle em elementos dentro de elementos com jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Quero aprender uma forma de dar toggle em uma lista dentro de uma lista de uma forma bem eficiente em `jQuery`.
 O jeito que tentei não funciona pq ao disparar o toggle em um, todos são afetados. Seria muito trabalhoso fazer para cada lista e suas respectivas listas.

> Resumindo. Como posso disparar um toggle em listas sem disparar as outras.

Aqui esta a forma como tentei

*Demo: [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/b9evw5nj/4/)*

---

```js
//Btn que dispara
jQuery('li.cat-parent > a:nth-child(1)').after('<i class="icon-toggle-cat">+</i>');

//Toggle
jQuery('.icon-toggle-cat').on('click', function(){   
    jQuery('li.cat-parent > ul.children').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="product-categories">
<li class="cat-item cat-item-61 cat-parent">
   <a href="#">Cachorros</a>
   <ul class="children">
<li class="cat-item cat-item-48"><a href="">Ambiente</a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-52 cat-parent">
   <a href="">Farmácia</a>
   <ul class="children">
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-54"><a href="">Antipulgas</a></li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-53"><a href="">Vermífugo</a></li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-55"><a href="">Vitaminas</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-35 cat-parent">
   <a href="">Higiene</a>
   <ul class="children">
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-38"><a href="">Tapete</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-33"><a href="">Petiscos</a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-21 cat-parent">
   <a href="">Rações</a>
   <ul class="children">
<li class="cat-item cat-item-133"><a href="">Fórmula Natural</a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-130"><a href="">Golden</a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-145 cat-parent">
   <a href="">Gran Plus</a>
   <ul class="children">
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-156"><a href="">Adulto Mini</a></li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-157"><a href="">Adulto RM</a></li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-155"><a href="">Filhote Mini</a></li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-154"><a href="">Filhote RM</a>
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente eu mudei o javascript, você esta um `selector` que estava pegando todos, você teria que pegar o relativo ao evento `click` para isso utilizei o `this` do evento que nesse momento é o `<i class='...'>+</i>` ficando assim:

```
jQuery(this).parent().find('> ul.children').toggle();

// Explicação 
//  jQuery(this) ou $(this) => neste momento o this e o elemento que foi clicado
//  .parent() => aqui eu pego o pai do elemento
//  .find('> ul.children') => usando com base o pai eu busco por ul.children
```

```js
jQuery('li.cat-parent > a:nth-child(1)').after('<i class="icon-toggle-cat">+</i>');

jQuery('.icon-toggle-cat').on('click', function(){
    jQuery(this).parent().find('> ul.children').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="product-categories">
<li class="cat-item cat-item-61 cat-parent">
   <a href="#">Cachorros</a>
   <ul class="children">
<li class="cat-item cat-item-48"><a href="">Ambiente</a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-52 cat-parent">
   <a href="">Farmácia</a>
   <ul class="children">
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-54"><a href="">Antipulgas</a></li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-53"><a href="">Vermífugo</a></li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-55"><a href="">Vitaminas</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-35 cat-parent">
   <a href="">Higiene</a>
   <ul class="children">
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-38"><a href="">Tapete</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-33"><a href="">Petiscos</a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-21 cat-parent">
   <a href="">Rações</a>
   <ul class="children">
<li class="cat-item cat-item-133"><a href="">Fórmula Natural</a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-130"><a href="">Golden</a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-145 cat-parent">
   <a href="">Gran Plus</a>
   <ul class="children">
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-156"><a href="">Adulto Mini</a></li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-157"><a href="">Adulto RM</a></li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-155"><a href="">Filhote Mini</a></li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-154"><a href="">Filhote RM</a>
   </ul>
</li>
```

[Tree Traversal](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/)